# Google map API KML + geocoding --> code troubles

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Still with my Map, still need help... ;o)

I have done a mix code between KML loading and geocoding.
All is working except the default 'a' KML (belgium map) which is NOT loading with the map.

Working exemple at this page :

Can somebody try to find the error on my code ?

Code & Map on test page at :

Thanks in advance to help an API newbie
Laurent

Html deleted for security reasons

Comment: That won't happen. You'll have to post some code here too (in case the link doesn't work in the future). Also post what the console says.

Comment: There is a javascript error on your map `Uncaught ReferenceError: initializeMap is not defined 9fa9db_481f9e1e44efaefb29fd3e286f2aa87b.html:59` on this line: 
`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);`

Answer (score 0):

1. your HTML is invalid. You are only allowed one `<body>` and one `<head>`. You have 3 `<body>` tags
2. You have multiple `<body onload=` functions.  (due to #1)

   ```
   <body onLoad="initialize()">
   <body onload="startup()">
   ```

combine them into a single `<body>` tag

```
    <body onload="initialize();startup();">
```

1. the link for "PRIV crèches-Kinder.-Nursery" is not correct, it returns INVALID_DOCUMENT

   ```
   e: {
       name: "PRIV crèches-Kinder.-Nursery",
       url: "https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?msid=208899208399411894595.0004d24cf21e2a254a10c&msa=0&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&t=h&z=9&vpsrc=1"
       },
   ```

should be:

```
    https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?authuser=0&msid=208899208399411894595.0004d24cf21e2a254a10c&msa=0&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&t=h&z=9&vpsrc=1&output=kml
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_KmlLayerCheckboxes.html)

Comment: Many Thanks Geocodezip !

Last thing, any solution to skip de vertical scrollbar aside the map ?

Comment: What vertical scrollbar? I don't see one on my [working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_KmlLayerCheckboxes.html).  The one on your map is a css/html issue; nothing to do with the Google Maps Javascript API v3.